# Web scraping from a dynamic consulting page in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get some information from a public site in order to perform a study. The site where I wish to get the information is the next: https://declaraciones.sri.gob.ec/mat-vehicular-internet/reportes/general/valoresAPagar.jsp. In this site you have to put a string in order to get some data. The problem is that you need to double click a button in order to display de information. For example, by using the string pyk0911 I have the next screen:
[image]

Then, I have to click on "Buscar" and I get the next screen:
[image]
After this screen, I have to click on "Ver Avaluos" and I will get this screen:
[image]
This final screen is the object I wish to extract and I save in a dataframe or in a list. The reason why I would like to obtain this information is because I have a lot of strings and it would be too long to be clicking and copying the results. The obstacles are the two double clicks. I want to build a function in `R` to insert the string and get all the information from the final screen with the details ,such as, `Modelo`, `Año`, and the variables `Periodo` and `Avaluo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several steps here. First, fill the form and submit, then extract the link to the table, then read the table.

```
library("rvest")
library("stringr")

url <- "https://declaraciones.sri.gob.ec/mat-vehicular-internet/reportes/general/valoresAPagar.jsp"

s <- html_session(url)
s_form <- html_form(s)[[2]]
filled_form <- set_values(s_form, placaCamv="pyk0911")
out <- submit_form(session=s, filled_form)

# out contains the link to the data table that pops up. This extracts that link
dat_path <- out %>% html_nodes("input.boton") %>% html_attr("onclick") %>%
  .[2] %>% str_extract("(?<=\\(\\').+(?=','avaluos)")

# then read the second table. I assume this is what you need. 
df <- read_html(paste0("https://declaraciones.sri.gob.ec", dat_path)) %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% .[[2]]
> df
   PerÃ­odo   AvalÃºo Impuesto
1      2016  1,699.00     8.50
2      2015  1,699.00     8.50
3      2014  1,699.00     8.50
4      2013  1,699.00     8.50
5      2012  1,699.00     8.50
6      2011  1,699.00     8.50
7      2010  1,699.00     8.50
8      2009  1,699.00     8.50
9      2008  1,699.00     8.50
10     2007  1,699.00     8.50
11     2006  3,398.00    16.99
12     2005  7,036.00    50.36
13     2004 10,554.00   111.08
14     2003 14,072.00   202.16
15     2002 16,990.00   300.00
16     2001  4,000.00    68.00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the bottom left of the window that is opened when you click "Ver Avaluos" you will see that you can export this data to excel. The easiest way to go about getting this data into a data frame with minimal manipulation (compared to web scraping) would be to save the data into an excel worksheet, then read in the data using the read.xls command found in the gdata package. This will automatically save it in a data frame.